# PHP & MySQL (Parse Error )

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in /root/folder/MySQLDao.php on line 67

However, everything seems fine. The chunk of code is:

```
public function registerUser($Facebookid, $firstname, $lastname, $FBpictureURL, $Gender, $UserEmail)
{
    $sql = "insert into Users set FacebookId=?, firstname=?, lastname=?, FBpictureURL=?, Gender=?, UserEmail=?";
    $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);  // Line 66
                                              // Line 67 is here
    if (!$statement)                          // Line 68
    throw new Exception($statement->error);

    $statement->bind_param("isssss", $Facebookid, $firstname, $lastname, $FBpictureURL, $Gender, $UserEmail);
    $returnValue = $statement->execute();

    return $returnValue;
}
```

**Edit**: I got lots of criticism about duplicate post, however, none of the answers solved my solution so far. I have of course checked StackOverflow before I post my question. Anyway, the ones still willing to help, I pasted my code in here: http://justpaste.it/phpsql

Comment: Read about queries first.

Comment: I think INSERT INTO  not use SET statement use VALUES() instead

Comment: You post 13 lines of code and an error message that refers to line 67. What are we looking for?

Comment: @Hobo Sapiens It is the snippet part of the code.. editing the OP now

Comment: @ChanomFirst I tried not using set either, however same error occurs.

Comment: The line you indicate as line 67 won't generate that error message. Are you looking at the right file?

Comment: your insert command is wrong, take a look here http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Insert-and-Update-Statement-Use-Prepared-Statement-P552.html

Comment: your sql query is wrong learn about sql queries http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: @syedmohamedumar I also used it in capital as if: `$sql = "INSERT INTO Users FacebookId=?, firstname=?, lastname=?, FBpictureURL=?, Gender=?, UserEmail=?";`

Comment: @syedmohamedumar Also, using parenthesis `$sql = "insert into Users (FacebookId=?, firstname=?, lastname=?, FBpictureURL=?, Gender=?, UserEmail=?)";` not working either.

Comment: @senty `"INSERT INTO Users (FacebookId, firstname, lastname, FBpictureURL, Gender, UserEmail) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"`

Comment: @LoganWayne I am going to get the question marks from POST. Am I making some logic mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

#### Note:

- Make sure that your given code is in `MySQLDao.php` file. Because it is hard to believe that it will return such error for that line (67), which is just blank.
- Your `insert` query setup looks okay if your extension supports `MySQL`

It would look like this in standard form:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Users (FacebookId, firstname, lastname, FBpictureURL, Gender, UserEmail) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

- Did you call the function correctly? Make sure that the passed-on variables for your `registerUser()` function is correctly passed-on from your `POST` form.

You may call your function like this (this is just an example way to call the function):

```
registerUser($_POST["Facebookid"],$_POST["firstname"],$_POST["lastname"],$_POST["FBPictureURL"],$_POST["Gender"],$_POST["UserEmail"]);
```

- If the code in your given [link](http://justpaste.it/phpsql) is your updated copy, you forgot "SET" in your query.

It should look like this:

```
"INSERT INTO Users SET FacebookId=?, firstname=?, lastname=?, FBpictureURL=?, Gender=?, UserEmail=?";
```

Comment: The logic I am trying to use is basically [the one being showed here](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/store-user-information-in-mysql-database/). I can't understand which part I am missing :/

Comment: This is my code full: http://justpaste.it/phpsql

Answer (score -1):

in your sql statement there is 6 columns and in your bind_param function you are providing 7 params if there is no need of "issss" then please remove it because i thing it is id and if you have settle it as primary key and auto increment  then you don't need to provide this argument
expected code:

```html
$statement->bind_param($Facebookid, $firstname, $lastname, $FBpictureURL, $Gender, $UserEmail);
```

Comment: 1. `$Facebookid`
2. `$firstname`
3. `$lastname`
4. `$FBpictureURL`
5. `$Gender`
6. `$UserEmail`
Total of 6. `isssss` is 6. So this answer is irrelevant.

Comment: @LoganWayne Facebookid is integer and the rest are variables. (Gender is char). Am I missing something?

Comment: @LoganWayne I am actually running `register.php ` and it `require` the MySQLDao.php. The error I am getting shows in `domain.com/register.php`; but the error is as it is in original post.

Comment: @senty - does your code from your post really comes from `MySQLDao.php` file?

Comment: No, I am trying to send the data from iPhone app [Swift (iOS)] but now, I am just opened www.domain.com/register.php without posting anything.

Comment: @senty - what are you currently getting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80028/discussion-between-logan-wayne-and-senty).